# How to convert a file path to a url

Tags: django

I have a text file that I'm looking to provide a link for download, generated by a class method in Django. The file path is absolute, e.g.

```
/var/www/django/project/app/somefile
```

Yet obviously I'll need to convert that to a webroot-based file path for the webserver to translate. I thought that there was some function in Django to do this rather than me having to manually truncate part of the absolute file path, but I can't seem to find it. Any suggestions?

One idea I had is to move this to the static directory, but I've never really used static files in previous projects, so I'm not too familiar with how it works, or if it is even the best way.

**Edit**: I should point out that I know this can be done in various ways, but I'm looking for the most pythonistic or Django-istic best practice.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation when you'd want to give a path to download one of your project's code files, or why you think there is any relation between the location of the code and the URLs. Can you explain further?

Comment: This isn't a code file. It's a generated file based on data in the django database. The application gathers a bunch of data from various sources, stores it in the database, then every day a file is generated that someone will download and likely print out. (it's a list of media that will need to be retrieved, so it's not useful to print it to a web page.)

Comment: I should also note that it takes a long time to generate this file, so instead of someone requesting it on-demand and waiting 20-30 minutes, I have a process that generates it every morning to a text file. I use a text file because other processes can use the file outside of django.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* place that the webserver can download files directly is in your static or media directories. The webserver must have no access at all to your code files; that would be an obvious security risk.

If you're generating a file for download, write it to the media directory.

Comment: Is there a functional difference between the media and static directories, or are they just two options to store non-code files?

Comment: Files in the static directory are, well, static; they are deployed with the app (or generated on deploy) and are used for things like JS and CSS assets. Media files are generated or uploaded by the user via the app.